# How do I create duplicate column in csv using python? (duplicate column should start from 2nd row)

Tags: python, csv

I have a file that contains following column. I want to create another column but values should be placed from 2nd row. First shall be empty or zero. How can I do it?.

`input.csv`

```
row 
100 
110 
100 
130 
.  
..
```

`output.csv`

```
dup  row 
0     100 
100   110 
110   100 
100   130 
130
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input = [100, 110, 100, 130]
output = [[], []]

output[0].append(0)
for i, row in enumerate(input):
    output[1].append(row)
    if i > 0:
        output[0].append(row)

f = "dup,row,"
for n in xrange(len(output[1])):
    f += "\n"+str(output[0][n])+","+str(output[1][n])+","

csv = open('output.csv','w')
csv.write(f)
csv.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The main logic is to use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to construct the output data. If input data is

```
in_data = [100, 110, 100, 130]
```

then

```
zip(in_data, in_data[1:])
```

gives:

```
[('100', '110'), ('110', '100'), ('100', '130')]
```

Rest is wrapping this using [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to get what you want. Here you go:

```
import csv

in_data = []
out_data = []
with open('input') as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        in_data.append(line.strip())

out_data.append((0, in_data[0]))
out_data.extend(zip(in_data, in_data[1:]))
out_data.append((in_data[-1], ))

with open('output', 'w') as out_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    for line in out_data:
        csv_writer.writerow(line)
```